# Tabla no toma la propiedad bordered

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Mi tabla parece no tomar la clase `table-bordered`, ¿qué está mal?

Este es mi código:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="row-fluid" style="margin-top: 10px;">
   <div class="row-fluid" style="margin-top:50px;">
       <div class="span12 table-responsive" style="margin-left: 0px;">
           <table id="detalleMigrante" name="detalleMigrante" class="table table-bordered">
               <thead>
                   <tr>
                       <th rowspan=2>Municipio </th>
                       <th rowspan=2>Area Frontera </th>
                       <th rowspan=2>Campamento/<br>Asentamiento </th>
                       <th rowspan="2">Procedencia</th>
                       <th colspan="3">N° Febriles<br>Encontrados</th>
                       <th rowspan="2">N° Gotas <br>Tomadas</th>
                       <th rowspan=2> Gota Gruesa<br>Positiva</th>
                       <th colspan=2> Tratamientos</th>
                       <th rowspan=3> Medidas Realizdas Contra <br>el Vector</th>
                       <th rowspan="2" style="width:45px;">Eliminar</th>
                   </tr>
                   <tr>
                       <th class="text-left">Actuales</th>
                       <th class="text-left">Recientes</th>
                       <th class="text-left">Tardios </th>
                       <th class="text-left">Curativos</th>
                       <th class="text-left">Preventivo</th>
                       <th style="width:30px;"></th>
                   </tr>

               </thead>
                <tbody id="content-tbody">
                    <tr id="tr-empty-legend"><td colspan="13">No se ha agregado ningun detalle</td></tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
            <input id="totalCount" name="totalCount" type="hidden" value="0" />
        </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Y así es cómo se ve:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola, tu pregunta no cumple con los requisitos mínimos para respuesta, corre el riesgo de ser ignorada o suspendida por políticas de la comunidad, revisa este enlace: [¿Como preguntar?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), te pedimos ser lo más especifico y al detalle de la misma, colocar el código html y css con la opción `ctrl + M` para poder ayudarte. Saludos.

Comment: La tabla parece tener los estilos de una [table-bordered](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/content/tables/#bordered-table). Incluso en tu captura de pantalla se ve bien. ¿Por qué dices que no toma la propiedad bordered?

Comment: no logro distinquir los bordes de la tabla

Comment: ¿Cómo que no logras distinguir los bordes? Se ven claramente tanto en el código de arriba como en la imagen. Si lo que quieres es cambiar su color, eso ya sería otra cosa. Pero la tabla está claramente tomando los estilos de `table-bordered`.

Answer (score 0):

respondo por aquí ya que no tengo suficiente reputación para hacerlo en los comentarios pero según la documentación en Bootstrap:

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/content/tables/#bordered-table

( Bordered table
Add .table-bordered for borders on all sides of the table and cells. )

El código que proporcionas está realizando el correcto funcionamiento de lo que indicas. Ya que pone bordes en toda la tabla y las celdas.

El único error que veo es en:

`<th rowspan="2" style="width:45px;">Eliminar</th>`

Ya que el rowspan está desbordando a la cantidad de la tabla.

Saludos.

Comment: No lo que les estoy diciendo es que Una las dos filas para que se vea como una sola celda, y quiza soy yo pero no alcanzo adistinguir los bordes

Answer (score 0):

Entiendo, parece ser que tu problema es con el monitor y el como está calibrado, ya que yo también puedo distinguir los bordes.

Ahora si la pregunta es como hacerlos más oscuros, puedes agregar en tu css la siguiente linea:

```
table.table-bordered thead th,
table.table-bordered td{
border-color: gray;  /*o color gris más oscuro o el color que desees*/
}
```

Así lo puedes ver en tu código:

```css
table.table-bordered thead th,
table.table-bordered td{
  border-color: gray; /*o color gris más oscuro o el color que desees*/
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="row-fluid" style="margin-top: 10px;">
   <div class="row-fluid" style="margin-top:50px;">
       <div class="span12 table-responsive" style="margin-left: 0px;">
           <table id="detalleMigrante" name="detalleMigrante" class="table table-bordered">
               <thead>
                   <tr>
                       <th rowspan=2>Municipio </th>
                       <th rowspan=2>Area Frontera </th>
                       <th rowspan=2>Campamento/<br>Asentamiento </th>
                       <th rowspan="2">Procedencia</th>
                       <th colspan="3">N° Febriles<br>Encontrados</th>
                       <th rowspan="2">N° Gotas <br>Tomadas</th>
                       <th rowspan=2> Gota Gruesa<br>Positiva</th>
                       <th colspan=2> Tratamientos</th>
                       <th rowspan=3> Medidas Realizdas Contra <br>el Vector</th>
                       <th rowspan="2" style="width:45px;">Eliminar</th>
                   </tr>
                   <tr>
                       <th class="text-left">Actuales</th>
                       <th class="text-left">Recientes</th>
                       <th class="text-left">Tardios </th>
                       <th class="text-left">Curativos</th>
                       <th class="text-left">Preventivo</th>
                       <th style="width:30px;"></th>
                   </tr>

               </thead>
                <tbody id="content-tbody">
                    <tr id="tr-empty-legend"><td colspan="13">No se ha agregado ningun detalle</td></tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
            <input id="totalCount" name="totalCount" type="hidden" value="0" />
        </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Ahora, veo que estás usando muchos estilos inline (del tipo: `style="width: 45px"`), no conozco la razón, pero deberías (es una recomendación) usar más los estilos de css en una hoja de estilos personalizada. Te será más facil darle mantenimiento a cada tabla.

Sí no es esto lo que buscas, escribeme en los comentarios para encontrar una mejor solución.